# Select from 2 tables

Tags: ms-access, select, ms-access-2007

I have 2 tables , First table is named Ticket

**Ticket**

```
ID
Subject
Owner
```

second table is

**TicketLinkedNames**

```
ID
TicketID
ContactID
LinkedReason
```

from the above structure you understand that I can link the table ticket with some other names so when I entered to the ticket form I can see in a grid below all the link names that are associated with this ticket. Am ok here?

My main problem is that I have one main form that I want to display all the tickets that the owner is some contact and also all the tickets that this contact is appear as link name in other tickets..
sort them out by unique records and display them.
I am  really confused of what kind of select query should I use, I have tried several like:

```
Select * from Ticket,TicketLinkedNames where Owner=ContactID
```

but returns wrong records. I have use `inner join` between `ID=TicketID` but also return wrong records.

I am really confused, please if someone could help me i will really appreciated.

I am using Microsoft Access 2007.

Comment: So same Id as you have in owner can come up in the ContactID?

Comment: hi thank you for your reply ,yes the Owner ID come up in ContactID , i think i should use union between this 2 tables?

Comment: Why not an `INNER JOIN ON Owner = ContactID`?

Comment: the table LinkedNames may or may not contain a link Name therefor if i use inner join in a case that a ticket dose not containg a linkname then will not return the ticket records instead of returning all the tickets that the owner is

Comment: In that case, you need a left join: `LEFT JOIN ON Owner = ContactID`

Comment: imagine a calendar where employees can create appointments and also they can link this appointment with other names ,those other names may be other employee names or some customers. when an employee open his calendar can see his appointments that is the owner and also can see the appointments that is a linked to other appointments

Comment: Perhaps you would like to post sample data, then we can all stop guessing?

Comment: sorry i dont have any data to show up, my data is the queries that am trying to find which is the correct according to the problem, i know that is not clear well , but as i said image the calendar example , i have use inner join ,right join, left join non of them seems to return the data am expecting to, i test the union query and it seems that is working. the data that am expecting to return is the following. ALL the Tickets that the owner is some owner and also all the tickets that the owner May or May not apper on the table LinkNames

Answer (score 0):

make 2 selects

**SUB select1:**
select distinct from table Ticket
for the owner that not contained in TicketLinkedNames

**SUB Select2:**
select distinct from table TicketLinkedNames
for the owner

then make a union between the 2

then you got the solution